# Laravel 5.5 recursive function to create menu

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have created a mysql table as below:

```
id | menuname          | parentid
---+-------------------+---------
 1 | dashboard         |        0
 2 | Content           |        0
 3 | Home Page Content |        2
 4 | Banners           |        2
 5 | Settings          |        0
 6 | Block Content     |        3
 7 | Site Content      |        3
```

So that the menu structure will look like:

- dashboard
- Content

  - Home Page Content

    - Block Content
    - Site Content
- Banners
- Settings

I have the controller:

```
public function index() {
    $data = array();

    $permissionRecord = Permission::all();
    $this->categoryTree($permissionRecord);

    dd('-end-);
    $data['permissionRecord'] = $permissionRecord;

    return view('Administrator.permission.permissionAdd',$data);
}

function categoryTree($permissionRecord, $parent_id = 0, $sub_mark = '')
{
    foreach($permissionRecord as $row) {
        echo $sub_mark.$row->name;

        $this->categoryTree($permissionRecord, $row->id, $sub_mark.'---');
    }
}
```

But this show the data :

> Dashboard---Dashboard------Dashboard---------Dashboard------------Dashboard---------------Dashboard------------------Dashboard---------------------Dashboard------------------------Dashboard---------------------------Dashboard------------------------------Dashboard---------------------------------Dashboard------------------------------------Dashboard

Please note, I dd() inside the controller and did not passed the data to the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've not accounted for the parent ID:

```
function categoryTree($permissionRecord, $parent_id = 0, $sub_mark = '')
{
    foreach($permissionRecord as $row) {
        if ($row->parentid == $parent_id) {
            echo $sub_mark.$row->name;

            $this->categoryTree($permissionRecord, $row->id, $sub_mark.'---');
        }
    }
}
```

Try that and see what happens - Note I've wrapped the recursive function call in an `if()` that checks if the current records parentId is equal to the parent ID passed into the method.

**To get it to display the items in an indented list:**

```
public function categoryTree($permissionRecord, $parent_id = 0)
{
    $html = '<ul>';

    foreach($permissionRecord as $row) {
        if ($row->parentid == $parent_id) {
            $html .= '<li>' . $row->menuname;

            $html .= $this->categoryTree($permissionRecord, $row->id, $html);

            $html .= '</li>';
        }
    }

    $html .= '</ul>';

    return $html;
}
```

Then just call:

```
$html = $this->categoryTree($permissionRecord);
```

**Example of it working with a unit test**

[image]

Comment: sorry, try changing `$row->name` to `$row->menuname`

Comment: Thanks a ton!! But how can I render this things into view? as you notices that I have dd() inside the controller.

Comment: Have updated with an example. It's not exactly how I would do it, but it's working.

Comment: $arr = $this->categoryTree($permissionRecord); - its show as null

Comment: Are you returning from the function instead of using `echo`?

Comment: Actually I need to call the same or pass the $data[html] to view from laravel controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171255/discussion-between-niladri-banerjee-uttarpara-and-phil-cross).